# MySQL (SQL) | LEFT JOIN DOES NOT RETURN ALL ROWS (NO FILTER APPLIED)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I would like to left join a calendar table with a sales table and return all sales by user by day (inclusive of all days **without** sales). For some reason, however, I only get the days **with** sales. As you can see below, there are no filters applied. What am I doing wrong here?

Below my SQL code, all tables and the wished final result.

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT
  calendar.date AS date,
  sales.user_id AS user_id,
  CASE
    WHEN sales.date = calendar.date THEN sales.quantity
    ELSE 0
  END AS quantity
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN sales
  ON calendar.date = sales.date
```

**DATE table** (from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31)

| date |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| ... |
| 2020-01-31 |

**SALES table**

| date | user_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | 10 |
| 2020-01-12 | 1 | 12 |
| 2020-01-20 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 13 |
| 2020-01-29 | 2 | 8 |

**WISHED RESULT**

| date | user_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | 10 |
| 2020-01-04 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-06 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-07 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-08 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-09 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-10 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-11 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-12 | 1 | 12 |
| 2020-01-13 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-14 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-15 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-16 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-17 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-18 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-19 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-20 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-21 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-21 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-22 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-23 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-24 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-25 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-26 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-27 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-28 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-29 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-30 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-31 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 13 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-04 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-06 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-08 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-09 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-10 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-11 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-12 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-13 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-14 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-15 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-16 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-17 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-18 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-19 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-20 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-21 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-21 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-22 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-23 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-24 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-25 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-26 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-27 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-28 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-29 | 2 | 8 |
| 2020-01-30 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-31 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you described, your query with the left join works as intended for me. Obviously, the user id values will be null for the dates when you do not have sales. sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b43bbb/1

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Despite the differences in behaviour, your result does't still match what I am currently trying to achieve. For each user_id there should be a full month worth of rows, from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31 (see above the "wished result" table).

Comment: The output you present as "the output from this query" should match. The current shown output is only possible if your problem is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is also unknown for the day without sales. To solve this, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  calendar.date AS date,
  su.user_id AS user_id,
  COALESCE( sales.quantity,0) AS quantity
FROM calendar
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM sales) su
LEFT JOIN sales
  ON calendar.date = sales.date AND sales.user_id=su.user_id
ORDER BY 2,1
```

see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b43bbb/9)